# Problems with grunt serve

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I have project, but i can't run him. I use WebStorm IDE and after enter **grunt serve** I catch next errors:

```
grunt serve
Loading "connect.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: C:\Users\TT\Documents\ES\frontend\node_modules\grunt-contrib-connect\node_modules\connect\node_modules\type-is\node_modules\mime-types\node_modules\mime-db\db.json: Unexpect
ed end of input
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module './source-map/source-map-generator'
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'jshint/src/cli'
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'pako/lib/zlib/messages'
Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: C:\Users\TT\Documents\ES\frontend\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\google-cdn\node_modules\cdnjs-cdn-data\external\cdnjs.json: Unexpected end of input
Loading "inline_angular_templates.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'domutils'

Running "serve" task
Warning: Task "connect:livereload" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-05-10 09:03:36 UTC)
loading tasks  18ms  █████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 56%
serve          11ms  ████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 34%
Total 32ms
```

Can you help me? How to fix it and what need install in order to this project earned?

Comment: Did you modify to 'db.json'? Maybe there is error 'unexpect syntax' end of input.
And any modules cannot find.
Check the the modules path and npm installed libra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

Here are the steps:

1. Remove nodejs and all npm's.
2. Install node
3. npm install
4. npm install -g bower
5. bower install
6. grunt serve

Success

Answer (score 0):

um... run:

```
$ grunt -v
```

this will give you the missing (corrupted) node_modules.  Sometimes things get corrupted or such.

I ran into this same problem with `grunt-google-cdn`  and reinstalled it. with `$ npm install grunt-google-cdn --save` and everything went fine after that :)

reinstalling everything is generally not required.